# Google AppEngine case insensitive for all url request how?

Tags: google-app-engine

This is with reference to following question..

[Switch off case sensitive URLs in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428431/switch-off-case-sensitive-urls-in-google-app-engine)

I am trying to use appengine as CDN. There is a lot of code written where javascript and css is being accessed in pages without considering case sensitivity. My App file looks like below..

```
 handlers:
- url: /themes/([^A-Z]+)
  static_files: themes/\1
  upload: themes/.*
- url: /.*
  handler: tolowercase.py
```

The problem is I want to make even themes as case insensitive. So what should be modification in tolowercase.py?

Also I didn't understand the first solution as I don't know about adding middleware in appengine (pardon my ignorance here)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What happens with the code as it is now? Are you sure you don't mean `- url: /themes/.*` in the second handler?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to serve static files with different capitalization than they were uploaded with - you'd need to upload them as app data instead, and serve them through your app.

Fixing your app to use the correct capitalization everywhere would be a much better idea.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what sort of pointers you want - simply go through your app, find all references to static files, and make sure they match the capitalization of the actual filename.

Comment: it's about "you'd need to upload them as app data instead, and serve them through your app"..but any way thanks for your help..I will figure it out.

Comment: You really don't want to do this unless you have no other option. It'll be slower, and it'll consume more resources to do so.